# Creating Nested custom fields

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, custom-field

I am using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/) to create custom fields and custom post-types. I am able to create repeater custom fields in the following format.

```
1         Dummy Name1     Location1
2         Dummy Name2     Location2
..... and so on
```

This field values are repeated and can be created n number of time. What I have trouble doing is this format

```
Session 2015-16
1         Dummy Name1     Location1
2         Dummy Name2     Location2
Session 2016-17
11         Dummy Name11     Location11
12         Dummy Name12     Location12
Session 2018-19
21         Dummy Name21     Location21
22         Dummy Name22     Location22
..... and so on
```

Is it possible to create such format with the same plugin? If not how is it possible to create such layout.

Thanks, Puneet

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that plugin but I know you could easily do that with [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) repeater fields

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: it's premium feature btw

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that with [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) plugin along with its [Group extension](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-group/).

The extension allows you reorganize your data in a better structure. Your data will be saved in an array instead of plain text field like normal WordPress fields.

It support **multi-level nested arrays** (along with the data) and **clone features** (repeating), so you can create as many clones as you want (both for the outer groups and the inner groups).

You can see a quick screenshot about it here (which is similar to what you asked):

[image: meta box group]

You can see more info about it on [its own page](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-group/).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugins and if you have any question, I'm happy to answer.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't see how it could be done with that plugin, perhaps take a look at [WP-Types](https://is.gd/nested_repeating_fields) they offer this. There is a video explainer on this page https://is.gd/nested_repeating_fields